# Automate Gimp plug-in-lens-distortion correction

Tags: gimp

I performed a lens distortion filter, tuning it until I had the settings that would compensate for the wide angle lens. I want to automate this so that I can perform the correction from the command line.

The documentation for plug-in-lens-distortion aligns with the gui parameters but I can't figure out how to automate this via a batch macro or script. I'd love to have a simple example of applying this lens distortion on an image and saving it back to a new filename.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! This question looks like it would be a better over at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), since it's about automation and not about programming.

Comment: I don't see an easy way to move it to SU but I'll create it over there and close it out here.

Comment: I think you'll have better chances of someone answering, but that's only if you're looking for kind of a general procedure. If you're looking for some specific code, SO is the best place, but people here generally expect a more specific programming question with some code that you've already tried

Comment: If you do open a question there, link it here!

Comment: Here is the SU entry, https://superuser.com/questions/1532232/automate-gimp-plug-in-lens-distortion-correction